# how to integrate htmlpurifier with symfony2?

Tags: class, symfony, namespaces

I am trying to integrate htmlpurifier into a symfony2 controller, but symfony2 assumes the class I am trying to instantiate is part of that vary controller, but it is not, it is an included class type frmo the htmlpurifier library.

Is there a way to escape the class name so that symfony2 doesn't look for it in the current namespace?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oh, just found it.

Instead of

```
require_once dirname('_FILE_') . '/plugins/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier();
```

I should put a leading backslash on the class name

```
require_once dirname('_FILE_') . '/plugins/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
$purifier = new \HTMLPurifier();
```

Comment: Just a suggestion the symfony2 way is to make HTMLPurifier a service and then using DI inject it into the controller

Comment: You can also use an existing bundle: https://github.com/Exercise/HTMLPurifierBundle

Answer (score 7):

I suggest to use the bundle version of HTMLPurifier for symfony2

you can found it on gitHub : https://github.com/Exercise/HTMLPurifierBundle

it's pretty easy to install with composer

Require the bundle in your composer.json file:

```
{
    "require": {
         "exercise/htmlpurifier-bundle": "*",
    }
}
```

Install the bundle:

```
$ composer update exercise/htmlpurifier-bundle
```

Register the bundle app/AppKernel.php :

```
public function registerBundles()
    {
        return array(
            new Exercise\HTMLPurifierBundle\ExerciseHTMLPurifierBundle(),
            // ...
        );
    }
```

you can use it as a service in a controller :

```
$purifier = $this->container->get('exercise_html_purifier.default');
$clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);
```

or a filter in a twig template :

```
{{ text|purify }}
```

also a [Form Data Transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) for the symfony2 form builder

it's all in the docs : https://github.com/Exercise/HTMLPurifierBundle